# Can't Instantiate Object in Constructor

Tags: c++, object, static, instantiation

I have a C++ header file like so:

```
class someClass : public someBaseClass
{
public:
    someClass();
    ~someClass();

private:
    Text playText; //declare text object
};
```

The C++ source file for it is:

```
someClass::someClass() : playText("Play") //instantiate text object
{
}

someClass::~someClass()
{
}
```

Then I have another class which has a static member of `someClass`:

```
class anotherClass
{
public:
    anotherClass();
    ~anotherClass();
private:
    static someClass className; //declare someClass object
};
```

The corresponding C++ source file:

```
anotherClass::anotherClass()
{
}

anotherClass::~anotherClass()
{
}

someClass anotherClass::className; //must do because its static
```

My problem is that when I close my application I get a error message that says:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x6903a9e0 in Breakout.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000054.
```

But strangely enough when I comment out the `: playText("Play")` part of my code in the someClass constructor the message goes away. I basically can't instantiate `playText` or else I get an error (which is only when I close the application never during run-time).

I am completely confused and can't find anything about why this happens so does anyone know why this happens and how I can fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: `class` is a **keyword**. Rename the member to something else.

Comment: Apart from the obvious problem that `class` is a keyword (and used here probably only for demonstration purposes?), I cannot see a serious problem on first glance. I think, the problem comes from some details of allocation in the real constructors, maybe the one of `someBaseClass`? Be aware that the static initialization runs before entering `main()` and that the order of initializing different static objects is undetermined. So, take care if you have more than one such object and they even reference each other...

Comment: Please post code of `Text` class.

Comment: Your example really doesn't give us any useful information. Consider that you say that commenting out the initialiation of `playText` causes the behavior to change. Don't you think that showing us `Text` or at least the relevant `Text::Text` would be useful in tracking down the issue?

Comment: The text object and constructor are from the SFML library.
http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1Text.php#a921ceeb09ced0f92ea7a675020557f61

Comment: This about this objectively – do you really think anyone can help you when you post code that is blatantly unrepresentative of your real code? Please see http://sscce.org/.

Comment: Run the code under a debugger. Otherwise, post enough code so that people can compile it, run it, and replicate your error. Does `someBaseClass` have a virtual destructor? How is your instance of `anotherClass` destroyed?

Answer (score 0):

`class` is a reserved keyword. You can't use it as an identifier here:

```
static someClass class;
```

You have to use another name for your static member variable. I'm surprised that this even compiles.

Comment: Actually, that wasn't the problem. I just used that name for demonstration purposes as it was the first name that popped into my head.

Comment: @ProgrammerGuy123 Then the code you posted is correct. If there's an error, it's certainly not part of that code.